# Android: how to set up CardView OnLongClick()?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-cardview, onlongclicklistener

I have a RecyclerView list of CardViews.  I click on a CardView and it uses an intent to launch a new activity, which shows a detail CardView to the user.  I want to add a LongClick to that new CardView that will launch a Dialog to ask the user if they would like to delete the CardView.  I tried the set up below.  The Dialog does not launch and I don't see the Toast.  What am I missing here?

```
public class CardViewDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    int position;
    CardView cardView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(detsinglecard_view);
    cardView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(CardViewDetails.this,"Dialog Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
            android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            DeleteCardViewFragment delCardViewDialog = new DeleteCardViewFragment();
            delCardViewDialog.show(fm,"delcardview dialog");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

activity_details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context="com.wimso.v060B.CardViewDetails">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" >
</include>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardViewDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    android:background="@color/background4main"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"  >

<TextView        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"        
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/skycard_filter2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"  />

**strong text**<android.support.v7.widget.CardView**strong text**

xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
**strong text**android:id="@+id/detsinglecard_view"**strong text**
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
android:longClickable="true"  >    
...
```

Comment: Looks like `(CardView) findViewById(detsinglecard_view);` returns null. Check whether `detsinglecard_view` is the correct id.

Comment: I added the layout code above which shows detsinglecard_view.  I'm not sure why app is crashing.

Comment: Seems like you have forgotten to call `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);`

Comment: You're missing a setContentView... How did you expect findViewById to work?

Comment: @cricket_007  Android newbie here, so I make lots of assumptions about my snippets working and then quickly find out how much I don't know yet.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` before accessing elements via `findViewById()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
    CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(detsinglecard_view);
        cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();  
            bundle2.putInt("itemPosition",position);
            android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            DeleteCardViewFragment delCardViewDialog = new DeleteCardViewFragment();               
            delCardViewDialog.setArguments(bundle2);
            delCardViewDialog.show(fm,"delcardview dialog");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok making progress.  So the app doesn't crash now and the new CardView loads properly.  When I longclick on the CardView though nothing happens.  Any thoughts?